# How to get array values in react js

Tags: reactjs

I want to get the updated values of an array. When I do a console.log I only get the length of the array and the new values aren't shown in the view. What is wrong here? [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fg685mkg/65/)

react js

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    owner: "Martin Schwatz",
    friends:  ["Pietro", "Mike", "Shawn", "Bilbo"],
  }
},
updateFriends: function(friend) {
  var a = this.state.friends.push(friend);
  console.log(a);
  this.setState({
    friends: a,
  });
},
```

Comment: @DavinTryon, but how would a react developer get the new values into the array?

Comment: `push` returns the length of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this one

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      owner: "Martin Schwatz",
      friends:  ["Pietro", "Mike", "Shawn", "Bilbo"],
    }
  },
  updateFriends: function(friend) {
    var newFriends = this.state.friends.concat(friend)
    this.setState({
      friends: newFriends,
    });
  },
  click: function(){
    this.updateFriends('VuVu')
  },
  render: function(){
    var listOfFriends = this.state.friends.map(function(item,i){
        return <li key={i}>{item}</li>
    }.bind(this))
    return <div>
        <button onClick={this.click}>Add VuVu</button>
        <hr/>
      {listOfFriends}
    </div>
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

It should work for you <[`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/62655/)>

Answer (score 1):

`push` returns the new length of the mutated array.  So, in the current code, `a` won't be the array *itself*.

Try this instead:

```
updateFriends: function(friend) {
  const newFriends = [ ...this.state.friends, friend ];
  this.setState({
    friends: newFriends,
  });
},
```